# What is the y-axis of this Oracle ASH Viewer?

Tags: oracle, monitoring

I am investigating different monitoring software for my database, and I stumbled upon this open source ASH Viewer. I noticed in the main graph on the y-axis for resource usage, it's labeled as "Active Sessions" with an axis of varying integers

Link: https://github.com/akardapolov/ASH-Viewer#how-it-works

[image]

I don't understand what "Active Sessions" is supposed to mean. Is this the CPU % utilization of the database?

Answer (score 0):

Since the link you included says the data is taken from [`V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1007.htm#REFRN30299), presumably these are the [wait event classes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/waitevents001.htm#BGGHJGII). In other words, the diagram shows how many sessions are waiting on each event class or actively executing ("CPU used") at any given time.

Comment: It looks exactly like the top activity graph of OEM

Comment: So the resource usage in this case is "CPU used"?

Comment: There's no "resource usage" in this chart, just the number of sessions and the things they are occupied with. "CPU used" here means the sessions are actively using CPU.